# How do I generate a swiper like list from a custom input?

Tags: shell

I need help with creating a tool.
So I have some lines selected by a region, that I need to feed line by line to a shell/python script. The output of shell/python script will be of the form:

```
0xabcd is in func1 (/path/to/file/a.c:233)
```

I want to show these lines in a swiper like buffer in this format:

```
func2(233) /path/to/file/a.c
func1(567) /path/to/another/file/b.c
```

so that I can use down and up arrows to visit these files. eg. using an up arrow will show file `/path/to/file/a.c` at line number 233 and
using a down arrow will show file `f.c` at line 567 etc.
something like this but with my own entries:
[imgur.com/gallery/uYtuOyg](https://%20imgur.com/gallery/uYtuOyg)

What is an efficient way I go about doing this in elisp ?

Comment: Please define "swiper-like buffer" in this context. How is it different from another buffer - please consider specifying its properties/mode/behavior.

Comment: In my experience swiper buffer or even swoop are mini buffers where I can just press up/down arrow on the entries and the corresponding entry would open up. I don't have to press ctrl+<up>/<down> arrow like in helm. Just up and down arrow and entries would be opened up. That's what I meant by "swiper-like buffer". Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Have you considered to write your own command using counsel/helm/ido/...? Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Please put all info specifying what you request in the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time.

Comment: @wasamasa, exactly but I am relatively new to lisp and need a simple application as an example to start on this. Like how do you split a region into separate lines in lisp and how do you get the output of an external application in lisp.